# Can not create mp4 video by exe but works fine with py

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, mp4, pyinstaller, opencv, python

Please see below code:

1. it can create mp4 video by execute py
2. but can NOT create mp4 by exe (this exe is from pyinstaller py).
3. and can create avi by exe ( codec XVID, format avi in videowriter). So it seems something wrong in pyinstaller with mp4 video?

   ```
   import tkinter as tk
   import cv2
   import numpy as np
   from PIL import ImageGrab

   window = tk.Tk()
   window.title('Basic Camera App2')
   window.geometry('350x250')

   def StartS():
       fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
       vid=cv2.VideoWriter(r"C:\\IQOutput\\123.mp4", fourcc, 12, (1270,710))
       while(True):
            img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,1280,720))
            img_np=np.array(img)
            frame=cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            vid.write(frame)
            cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
            key=cv2.waitKey(1)
            if key==27:
               break
       vid.release()
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()

   bstarts = tk.Button(window, text='RecScr', font=('Arial', 8), bg='light 
   pink', width=5, height=1, command=StartS)     
   bstarts.place(x=130, y=10, anchor='nw')

   window.mainloop()
   ```

Comment: what was the error you were getting.

Comment: not sure what happen, now "codec XVID, format avi in videowriter" even can not show up 'Basic Camera App2' window in exe but good in py. NOT got error during executing py, during pyinstaller, double click "Basic Camera App2.exe". My python version is 3.6.3, my pc is wn7 professional sp1, 64bit.

Comment: answer above small stupid wrong "now codec XVID, format avi in videowriter"\ even can not show up UI window", because I do not add "window.mainloop()" in the end of scripts.

Comment: I find other way, I use python to call oCam (very good screen shot and screen record application), and use tkinter to press hotkeys of screen record in Ocam, now it works good. Now I do not need to use cv2.